# How to convert 11 digit hexadecimal number to unique 11 digit decimal number in Java?

Tags: java, data-conversion

We have a very weird requirement to convert 11 digit hexadecimal number ( range from (A0000000001 ~ AFFFFFFFFFF) ) to 11 digit decimal number. And there should be 1:1 mapping between hexadecimal to integer. Is there a way to do this in Java ?

Answer (score 8):

This is not possible, in Java or in any other language or system.  This impossibility is a fundamental property of numbers and set theory.

Since the leading `0xA` does not change, what you actually have is a 10-hex digit value, or 40 bits worth of data.

This encompasses about 1.1 x 10<sup>12</sup> possible values, so it is not possible to map this to an 11-digit decimal number, which by definition has only 10<sup>11</sup> possible values.

Based on the comments I'm going to make this more explicit.  Start with `0xA0000000000` and map that to decimal `00000000000`, then increment both by 1 to establish a one-to-one correspondence between members of the two sets and repeat:

```
0xA0000000000 -> 00000000000
0xA0000000001 -> 00000000001
0xA0000000002 -> 00000000002
...
0xA0000000010 -> 00000000016
...
0xA0000000100 -> 00000000256
...
0xA0000001000 -> 00000004096
...
0xA174876E7FF -> 99999999999
...
0xA174876E800 -> oops! overflow!  too many digits
```

Put another way, the size of the set of all hex values between `0xA0000000000` and `0xAFFFFFFFFFF` is larger than the set of all decimal values between `00000000000` and `99999999999`.

Comment: He wants this mapped to 11 digits from 10 digits hex the A digit remains the same

Comment: He explicitly said ***decimal*** output.  You cannot map over a trillion distinct values to an 11-digit number.

Comment: yeah I'm just pointing out that he only doing this from a range and does not need all potential values.

Comment: A0000000001  =  12094627905535
 AFFFFFFFFFF =  10995116277761 
 Range Of Values = 1099511627774
#Of unique digits required 13

Comment: @JimGarrison As Johnny pointed that i don't want to map trillion distinct values to 11 digit number. All i want is 11 digit unique number from 10 digit HEX as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

```
String hexNumber = ... 
int decimal = Integer.parseInt(hexNumber, 16);
```

Not sure if you need to display ten characters or not.  If so, here is some code to convert it into a string and pad leading zeros.

```
String decNumber = Integer.toString(decimal);


public static String padLeadingZeros(String data, int requiredLength){
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    int numLeadingZeros = requiredLength - data.length();
    for (int i=0; i < numLeadingZeros; i++){
        sb.append("0");
    }
    sb.append(data);
    return sb.toString();
}
```